# Outputtable trait in C++: SFINAE always picks one implementation over the other

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I followed one of the threads over here on S.O on how to implement an Outputtable trait class to check at compile time whether a type can be output on `std::ostream`. Implementation of the class is the following:

```
template<typename U>
        struct OstreamOutputableTrait
        {
            template<typename T>
            static decltype(std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<T>(), std::true_type{} )
            IsOstreamOutputtable(std::ostream& os, const T& var) {}

            // for vector<T>
            template<typename T>
            static std::false_type IsOstreamOutputtable(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& var)
            {}

            template<typename > static auto IsOstreamOutputtable(...) {
                return std::false_type {};
            }
            static const auto value =
                    decltype(IsOstreamOutputtable(std::declval<std::ostream&>(), std::declval<U>()))::value;
        };

// operator implementation
        template<typename Key, typename T>
        std::ostream& operatorImpl(std::ostream& os, const std::map<Key,T>& map, const std::true_type& ) {
            for(auto it = map.begin(); it!= map.end(); ++it)
                os << "(" << (*it).first << " ; " << (*it).second << ")" <<"\n";
            return os;
        }

        template<typename Key, typename T>
        std::ostream& operatorImpl(std::ostream& os, const std::map<Key, T>& map, const std::false_type& ) {
            os << "\nElements of the map are not printable.\n";
            return os;
        }

        // operator << on <Key, value> maps
        template<typename Key, typename T>
        std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::map<Key, T>& map)
        {
            // redirect using SFINAE to correct Impl of the operator<< : ty always returns true!
            auto ty = std::integral_constant<bool,
            OstreamOutputableTrait<typename std::decay_t<T> >::value &&
            OstreamOutputableTrait<typename std::decay_t<Key> >::value>();

            operatorImpl(os, map, ty);
            return os;
        }
```

Problem I have is that variable `ty` in the function above ALWAYS returns `std::true_type`. Does that mean that both `<Key,T>` typenames of the `std::map` template class are outputtable on `std::ostream` by default in the STL ?  If anyone can explain where I may be doing something wrong, that would help me a lot.

Thanks
Amine

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in declaring the variadic version of `IsOstreamOutputtable()`

```
template <typename>
static auto IsOstreamOutputtable (...)
 { return std::false_type {}; }
```

You declare it as **template** function with a template parameter that can't be deduced from the arguments.

So, when you call the function from `decltype()`

```
static const auto value =
   decltype(IsOstreamOutputtable(std::declval<std::ostream&>(), std::declval<U>()))::value;
```

the compiler can't take in considerations the variadic version.

Solutions.

(1) you can explicit the template parameter calling `IsOstreamOutputtable()`

```
   // ..........................VVV   explicit template parameter
   decltype(IsOstreamOutputtable<U>(std::declval<std::ostream&>(), std::declval<U>()))::value;
```

so the compiler can use the variadic version,

Problem: this solution doesn't works for the `std::vector` version

(2) (better) you can make the variadic version of `IsOstreamOutputtable()` a non-template one

```
// no needs of template
static auto IsOstreamOutputtable (...)
 { return std::false_type {}; }
```

Off Topic: the `IsOstreamOutputtable()` methods are called only inside a `decltype()`, so there is no needs of define, you have only to declare them . (and if you define them, please, be coherent: the body can't be empty for a method returning `std::true_type`).

Using also trailing return type, and other minor simplifications, your typewriting can be a little reduced

```
template <typename U>
struct OstreamOutputableTrait
 {
   template <typename T>
   static auto IsOstreamOutputtable (T const & var)
      -> decltype( std::declval<std::ostream&>() << var, std::true_type{} );

   // special case for vector<T>
   template <typename T>
   static std::false_type IsOstreamOutputtable (std::vector<T> const &);

   static std::false_type IsOstreamOutputtable (...);

   static constexpr auto value
      = decltype(IsOstreamOutputtable(std::declval<U>()))::value;
 };
```

Comment: thanks so much @max66! I will follow your guidelines from now on. So if I understand correctly, using no parameter inside the variadic template<typename> definition of the function, the compiler considers it as a non-templated function, and is therefore ignored at compilation time for the SFINAE mechanism? thanks

Comment: @Amine - Sorry but I don't understand what do you mean with "using no parameter inside the variadic template<typename> definition of the function". Please, can you write a practical example (maybe in the question)?

Answer (score 0):

@max66,

My idea was that:

```
template<typename T>
            static decltype(std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<T>(), std::true_type{} )
            IsOstreamOutputtable(std::ostream& os, const T& var) {}
```

would check that for each type `T` that can be output using the `operator<<`, decltype would return the the type of `std::true_type`. In this context, the variadic overload:

```
template<typename > static auto IsOstreamOutputtable(...) {
                return std::false_type {};
            }
```

doesn't have any utility but to cause confusion. Having said that, if I use the syntax:

`decltype(IsOstreamOutputtable<U>(std::declval<std::ostream&>(), std::declval<U>()))::value;`

would the variadic function have priority over the first one that returns `std::true_type`?